# Why does reusing a UIView as .leftView for two UITextFields causes massive memory usage

Tags: swift, xcode

To create a padding effect in **Swift 4.2** on a `UITextField`, I have used the following technique:

```
import UIKit


class BioController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 27, height: self.nameTextField.frame.height))
        self.nameTextField.leftView = paddingView
        self.nameTextField.leftViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

This approach worked as expected and perfectly fine.

[image]

To reuse the `paddingView` and get the same effect on the second text field I have changed the code to:

```
import UIKit


class BioController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 27, height: self.nameTextField.frame.height))
        self.nameTextField.leftView = paddingView
        self.nameTextField.leftViewMode = .always

        self.ageTextField.leftView = paddingView
        self.ageTextField.leftViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

The first thing I had noticed was that the controller did not appear anymore on `self.present(` (of the former controller). While investigating this issue I have noticed:

[image]

The memory was blowing up fast and hard! Removing `self.ageTextField.leftView = paddingView` and creating its own view solved the issue. But why did this happen in the first place? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that causes the extreme memory use you are showing, but I can tell you not to do that. A UIView can only be in one place in the view hierarchy. You can't put a UIView in 2 different places like that, and **should** not do it.

"Doc, it hurts when I do **this**!"

Doctor: "Then don't to that!"